# s:text name s:if tag

Tags: jsp, struts2

```
<tr id="isBillable" style="display: block;">
    <td width="120px"><s:text name="Is_Billable" /><span class="ibm-required">*</span>
    </td>
    <td width="300px">
        <fieldset style="border: 0 none; color: black;">
            <legend class="ibm-access"><s:text name="Is_Billable" /><span class="ibm-required">*</span>
            </legend>
            <s:if test="%{(reqId == null) || (reqId == '')}">
                <s:radio list="#{'N':'NO','Y':'YES'}" title="Is_Billable" name="isBillabletype" id="isBillabletype" disabled="disable" onclick="billableType(this);  " />
            </s:if>
            <s:else>
                <s:radio list="#{'N':'NO','Y':'YES'}" title="Is_Billable" name="isBillabletype" id="isBillabletype" disabled="true" onclick="billableType(this);  " />
                <s:hidden name="isBillabletype" />
            </s:else>
        </fieldset>
    </td>
</tr>
```

What is the meaning of `<s:text name="Is_Billable" ...>` In what sense is the Is_Billable referred as (it's functionality)? What is the point of `<s:if>` and `<s:else>`, they contain the same code in both cases? Please explain the part of the code. I am very new to this. Thank you.

Comment: There's no magic tags are running on server, not in your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All any of this does (and JSP generally speaking does) is produce HTML to be sent to the browser.  So if you want to see what it does, go to the page in your browser. Then right click on the page and choose *View Source*.

Take a look at the HTML that was produced by the JSP and you will see what its doing.  Where you see the custom Spring tags like `<s:text name="Is_Billable"/>` and `<s:radio .... />` it will have been replaced by regular HTML.

Also, on the if-else, look harder: the code is *not* the same.